# Why Image Magick 7 is not supporting opencl?

Tags: imagemagick, opencl, centos7

I have installed ImageMagick 7.0.2-1 with enabled opencl and Magick++.

But while running program, it is showing

```
Error: ImageMagick: unable to access configure file `/home/local/rock/.cache/ImageMagick/ImagemagickOpenCLDeviceProfile' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/708
```

I have referred the link `

> https://superuser.com/questions/1111913/imagemagick-7-opencl-gpu#1111913

But no solution. How to resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that path writable by the ImageMagick process? You can also configure the OpenCL options with `InitImageMagickOpenCL` method. [See examples here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/opencl.php).

Comment: But this problem is not with ImageMagick 6. Why so?

Comment: By default, it has to be /home/local/rock/.cache/ImageMagick. If I remove sudo while running my program, it is showing "Error: ImageMagick: unable to write blob '/home/local/rock/.cache/ImageMagick/magick_opencl_Intel(R)_HD_Gr‌​aphics_BroadWell_U-Processor_GT2_2062163c_64.bin': File exists @ error/blob.c/BlobToFile/266"